# Python function that prints n times string s1 separated by string s2

Tags: python, function

I'm stuck with this problem for a few days. I wanna create a function that does this with only one line of code:

```
>>> func1(1, '*', '-')
'*'
>>> func1(2, '*', '-')
'**-**'
>>> func1(3, '*', '-')
'***-***-***'
>>> func1(4, 'z', 'Z')
'zzzzZzzzzZzzzzZzzzz'
```

So I thought of something like this:

```
def func(n, s1, s2):
    print(n * (n * s1 + s2)
```

Which would print this:

```
>>>func(2, '*', '-')
**-**-
```

Is there any way to get rid of the last "-"?

Comment: See the `join` string method.

Comment: [link](https://geekflare.com/python-remove-last-character/)
This may help you, although it might not be the cleanest answer

Comment: If you want to do it in a single line: `s2.join([n * s1]*n)` - create a list with n elements consisting of `s1` repeated `n` times. Join these elements together with `s2` as the separator.

Answer (score 3):

you could simply not print the last element

```
def func(n, s1, s2):
    print((n * (n * s1 + s2))[:-len(s2)])
```

Comment: Make sure to use `-len(s2)` to make it work properly

Comment: good point, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `join`.

```
>>> def func(n, s1, s2):
...     return s2.join([s1 * n] * n)
```

Usage:

```
>>> func(1, '*', '-')
'*'
>>> func(2, '*', '-')
'**-**'
>>> func(3, '*', '-')
'***-***-***'
>>> func(4, 'z', 'Z')
'zzzzZzzzzZzzzzZzzzz'
```